# Why does my CSS custom stylesheet rule get overwritten and not applied in SAPUI5?

Tags: css, sapui5

I've created a SAPUI5 application with a List and want to color the CustomListItems with css.

My style gets always overridden by sap-style. I don't know how to order this...

I've also tried to implement style direct in element...

Can someone please help me?

**CSS**

```
.itemOpen{
  background-color: #FA5858
 }
```

**XML-Page**

```
<Page title="Simple Kanban Board">
    <content>
        <HBox width="100%">
            <List id="lstOpenItems" items = "{kanban>/OPEN}" width="100%" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
                <headerToolbar>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Title text="offene Aufgaben" level="H2" />
                    </Toolbar>
                </headerToolbar>
                <items >
                    <CustomListItem class="itemOpen" style="background-color:#FA5858">
                        <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom">
                            <Title titleStyle="H3" text="{kanban>NAME}"  />
                            <Text text="Description1" />
                        </VBox>
                        <!-- <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
                            <Text text="Description2" />
                            <CheckBox selected="{NotApplicable}" select="onNACheckBoxSelect" />
                            <RatingIndicator value="{RatingValue}" maxValue="{MaxValue}" change="onRatingChanged" />
                            <Text text="{ path: 'RatingValue', formatter: '.formatter.ratingText' }" />
                        </VBox> -->
                    </CustomListItem>
                </items>
            </List>
        </HBox>
    </content>
</Page>
```

[image: Screenshot from Chrome Element Inspector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please add `!important` in your `style.css` to the respective style attribute:

```
.itemOpen {
  background-color: #FA5858 !important;
}
```

the `!important` attribute gives first priority to the rule of the respective element. it says that this is the rule that needs to be applied to the respective element. a rule with the `!important` attribute is going to overwrite other more specific css rules.

Comment: Works great! !important seems to be important :)

Comment: After I struggled a long time to find a way to load the CSS after loading the view, as opposed to in the manifest,json (where it would also just get overwritten as per the OP here), I settled on this solution and I can confirm it works. Thank you!